# How do I unwield a weapon of distortion without being banished?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

What are the best methods to unwield a weapon of distortion without risking being banished, or at least reducing this risk?

This are the ones I can think of right now:

- Just unwield it and pray for the best?
- Tukima's Dance [doesn't seems to work](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Tukima%27s_Dance).
- Enter The Abyss through a portal. [It seems this is the safest method](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/The_Abyss#Entering_the_Abyss), but it's unavailable in the early/mid game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't one, besides going into the abyss, but that has the same effect as banishment. You used to be able to use a Scroll of Brand Weapon to remove the brand, but that's been fixed. The only thing for you to do is unwield it and cross your fingers.

Comment: I forgot that you can't enter and leave immediately from the Abyss.. so yeah, it's the same as banishment :(

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan As of one of the more recent versions, getting banished while in the abyss will send you deeper into the abyss. So it's definitely better to unwield a distortion weapon when you aren't in the abyss already.

Answer (score 2):

As of (If I recall correctly) 0.14, worshippers of Lugonu can unwield distortion safely at any piety level. Mind, it's generally not worth switching religion over, or incurring your previous god's wrath; if you're at a point where you can survive that, you can probably survive Abyss:1.

Comment: So, the safest method is to worship Lugonu, but isn't really practical for *those* situations :P

Comment: To add some more impractical options: The Shining One or Kikubaaqudgha will, as a powerful, valuable ability usable only once per game, change the brand on your weapon in a way that bypasses distortion.  Don't waste it!